# ImageManager class, what is it? where is it?

Tags: android, adapter, listadapter, android-gridview

I notice they use a class called ImageManager in the following code.  What is this class or how do you make it?   what is ImageManager?

I saw many examples on various websites and they use this and never explain it or show any code. Looking at the import statemens I guess that it something they always leave out in the code examples.

```
   package com.google.android.panoramio;

   import android.content.Context;
   import android.database.DataSetObserver;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   /**
   * Adapter used to bind data for the main list of photos
   */
   public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   /**
    * Maintains the state of our data
    */
   private ImageManager mImageManager;

   private Context mContext;

   private MyDataSetObserver mObserver;

  /**
   * Used by the {@link ImageManager} to report changes in the list back to
   * this adapter.
   */
   private class MyDataSetObserver extends DataSetObserver {
   @Override
   public void onChanged() {
   notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

   @Override
   public void onInvalidated() {
   notifyDataSetInvalidated();
   }
   }

   public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
   mImageManager = ImageManager.getInstance(c);
   mContext = c;
   mObserver = new MyDataSetObserver();

   mImageManager.addObserver(mObserver);
   }

   /**
   * Returns the number of images to display
   * 
   * @see android.widget.Adapter#getCount()
   */
   public int getCount() {
      return mImageManager.size();
   }

   /**
    * Returns the image at a specified position
    * 
    * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItem(int)
   */
   public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mImageManager.get(position);
   }

  /**
  * Returns the id of an image at a specified position
  * 
  * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItemId(int)
  */
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    PanoramioItem s = mImageManager.get(position);
    return s.getId();
  }

 /**
 * Returns a view to display the image at a specified position
 * 
 * @param position The position to display
 * @param convertView An existing view that we can reuse. May be null.
 * @param parent The parent view that will eventually hold the view we return.
 * @return A view to display the image at a specified position
 */
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 View view;
 if (convertView == null) {
 // Make up a new view
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_item, null);
 } else {
 // Use convertView if it is available
 view = convertView;
 }
 PanoramioItem s = mImageManager.get(position);

 ImageView i = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
 i.setImageBitmap(s.getBitmap());
 i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture_frame);

 TextView t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
 t.setText(s.getTitle());

 t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.owner);
 t.setText(s.getOwner());
 return view;
 }

 }
```

Comment: Where did you get this code from? Post the link to the website. The `ImageManager` class could be just about anything. Without looking at the context, it would be difficult to figure out.

Comment: here are two examples of many for this same code that includes imageManager,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102968/android-in-gridview-how-to-add-a-label-on-the-image   and    http://searchco.de/codesearch/view/2543100

Comment: Well, the second link has your answer. It lists an SVN Checkout link at the top. Follow that link and you will see _Panoramio_ in the list. Click on that, and you have the entire project. Browse through the `src` folder and you will find your mysterious `ImageManager` class. ;-)

Comment: This is the direct link for that project: http://apps-for-android.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Panoramio/

Comment: thank you.  it makes sense now.  i saw so many posts of this same code where there was no explanation of what where this class came from.  it was so common for there to be no explanation that i did not expect there to be a link so i did not notice it.    if you repost you comment as an answer, i can check it as the correct answer to the question.

Comment: Nope. I wouldn't. It's not really a solution. People miss things all the time. I do too. ;-) Glad to have helped.